# What is the best way to organize a react project with reusable component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently on a React project. I don't have a direct mentor so I don't know if I'm going in the right direction.

For my application, I would like to use as many reusable components as possible.

Currently, the components' folder is organized by category/view

For example, I have a button folder which groups around ten buttons (delete, send, change language, next...).

**here is the structure of my code at the moment :**

A part of my header who have multiple button

```
import { Refuse } from 'components/buttons/Refuse';
import { Validate } from 'components/buttons/Validate';

export const Header = () => {

return (
<>
 <Refuse
      offerData={offerData}
      setValue={setValue}
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      register={register}
      watch={watch}
            />
          )}{' '}
 <Validate
      register={register}
      setError={setError}
      offerData={offerData}
      setValue={setValue}
      watch={watch}
      clearErrors={clearErrors}
          />
</>
)}
```

and then in the folder 'components/button' a file for validate button

```
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { setActiveButton } from '../../features/buttons.slice';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { AdminValidation } from '../popup/AdminValidation';

export const Validate = ({
  offerData,
  setError,
  watch,
  setValue,
  clearErrors,
  register,
}) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const isLoading = useSelector((state) => state?.orders.loading);
  const userRole = useSelector((state) => state.user?.userGroup);
  const [ValidatePopup, setValidatePopup] = useState();

  return (
    <>
      {userRole?.includes('1') && userRole?.includes('3') ? (
        <Button
          disabled={
            offerData?.Status === 1 ||
            offerData?.Status === 3 ||
            offerData?.Status === 4
          }
          variant="contained"
          type={
            (offerData?.Paiement === 'Classique' ||
              offerData?.Paiement === 'Visa') &&
            offerData?.Status === 2
              ? 'button'
              : 'submit'
          }
          onClick={() => {
            if (
              (offerData?.Paiement === 'Classique' ||
                offerData?.Paiement === 'Visa') &&
              offerData?.Status === 2
            ) {
              setValidatePopup(true);
            } else {
              dispatch(setActiveButton('Valider'));
            }
          }}
        >
          {isLoading ? <> Chargement</> : <> Valider</>}
        </Button>
      ) : (
        <Button
          disabled={
            isLoading ||
            (userRole?.includes('1') && offerData?.Status !== 0) ||
            (userRole?.includes('2') && offerData?.Status !== 1) ||
            (userRole?.includes('3') && offerData?.Status !== 2)
          }
          variant="contained"
          type={
            (offerData?.Paiement === 'Classique' ||
              offerData?.Paiement === 'Visa') &&
            offerData?.Status === 2
              ? 'button'
              : 'submit'
          }
          onClick={() => {
            if (
              (offerData?.Paiement === 'Classique' ||
                offerData?.Paiement === 'Visa') &&
              offerData?.Status === 2
            ) {
              setValidatePopup(true);
            } else {
              dispatch(setActiveButton('Valider'));
            }
          }}
        >
          {isLoading ? <> Chargement</> : <> Valider</>}
        </Button>
      )}
      <AdminValidation
        setError={setError}
        register={register}
        setValue={setValue}
        ValidatePopup={ValidatePopup}
        setValidatePopup={setValidatePopup}
        watch={watch}
        clearErrors={clearErrors}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

and a file for Refuse button

```
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import React from 'react';
import { setActiveButton } from '../../features/buttons.slice';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { FormDialog } from '../popup';
import { setOpen } from '../../features/popup.slice';

export const Refuse = ({ register, watch, setValue, offerData, errors }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const isLoading = useSelector((state) => state?.orders.loading);
  const userRole = useSelector((state) => state.user?.userGroup);

  return (
    <>
      <Button
        disabled={
          isLoading ||
          (userRole?.includes('1') &&
            userRole?.includes('3') &&
            offerData?.Status !== 0) ||
          (userRole?.includes('1') &&
            userRole?.includes('3') &&
            offerData?.Status !== 2) ||
          (userRole?.includes('1') &&
            !userRole?.includes('2') &&
            offerData?.Status !== 0) ||
          (userRole?.includes('2') &&
            !userRole?.includes('1') &&
            offerData?.Status !== 1) ||
          (userRole?.includes('3') && offerData?.Status !== 2)
        }
        variant="text"
        type="button"
        onClick={() => {
          dispatch(setOpen(true));

          dispatch(setActiveButton('Refuser'));
        }}
      >
        {' '}
        {isLoading ? <> Chargement</> : <> Refuser</>}
      </Button>{' '}
      <FormDialog
        offerData={offerData}
        register={register}
        watch={watch}
        setValue={setValue}
        errors={errors}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

**I was thinking of deleting all these files to create only one component, called 'button' which I would reuse for each action as below:**

my reusable button will look like this

```
import { Button } from '@mui/material';

export const ButtonComponent = ({ type, style, action, texte, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <Button type={type} onClick={action} {...props}>
      {texte}
    </Button>
  );
};
```

my Header page will call the reusable button

```
import { Refuse } from 'components/buttons/Refuse';
import { Validate } from 'components/buttons/Validate';

export const Header = () => {

return (
<>
  <> <ButtonComponent
                disabled={
                  isLoading ||
          (userRole?.includes('1') &&
            userRole?.includes('3') &&
            offerData?.Status !== 0) ||
          (userRole?.includes('1') &&
            userRole?.includes('3') &&
            offerData?.Status !== 2) ||
          (userRole?.includes('1') &&
            !userRole?.includes('2') &&
            offerData?.Status !== 0) ||
          (userRole?.includes('2') &&
            !userRole?.includes('1') &&
            offerData?.Status !== 1) ||
          (userRole?.includes('3') && offerData?.Status !== 2)
                }
                action={() => {
           dispatch(setOpen(true));

          dispatch(setActiveButton('Refuser'));}
                type={'button'}
                texte={isLoading ? langue?.loading : langue?.refused}
                variant="text"
              />
         <FormDialog
    offerData={offerData}
    register={register}
    watch={watch}
    setValue={setValue}
    errors={errors}
  /></>


          <ButtonComponent
            //same here but for validate
          />
</>
)}
```

The problem is that the pages calling the buttons end up with more imports, more lines of code.

So I was finally wondering, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a "best" way. You'll end up with thousands answers all describing a subjective approach. But I think you need some help in structuring your components instead.

You mention your "reusable button" but that's a proxy for the properties `action` and `texte`. The rest of the properties could have been applied on `<Button />` directly.

First of all react components will not render if you return `false` while rendering. So you can change your logic to early returns instead. Which makes your components more readable.

```
const MyButton = () => {

   if (![statement1]) {
       return false;
   }

   if (![statement2]) {
       return false;
   }

   // if all negative statements do not match, render it
   return (
      <button />
   )
}
```

Second tip, don't mix business logic in your components. Create a separate file which stores business logic.

```js
# offer_logic.js

export canRefuse = (offer) => {
   // your business logic here to determine if an offer can be refused
   return [your_logic];
}
```

You can then use this in your Components. It's up to you which component (either button or where the button is rendered).

```
import OfferLogic from 'offer_logic';

// ... 


{OfferLogic.canRefuse(offer) && (
    <Button onClick={..}>Refuse offer</Button>
)}

// or 

const RefuseButton = (offer) => {
   if (!OfferLogic.canRefuse(offer)) {
       return false;
   }
   return (
      <Button onClick={..}>Refuse offer</Button>
   );
}
```

If your `offer` is a model, you could add the logic to your models instead.

This should prevent you from building complex components and less abstraction in your code due to duplication. It should also make your components more readable and more testable.

A last suggestion would be that the data your api (or other data source) will produce could be enhanced with more logic. For example let your backend determine if an offer can be refused or not, so your app doesn't have to determine this. There are many methods you can use for your backend, but I'll leave that out of here since that's not your question.